# Получить значения data-id всех элементов с определенным классом на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть n-ое количество элементов с одинаковым классом и атрибутом data-id
Как получить значения data-id всех элементов с данным классом?

```
<span class="select" data-id="1">one</span>
<span class="select" data-id="2">two</span>
<span class="select" data-id="3">three</span>...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для преобразования одной коллекции в другую и в обычном яваскрипте есть [метод map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и в jQuery есть [метод map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

Эти методы позволяют по полученной коллекции элементов, получить коллекцию значений атрибута, например

```js
//jQuery
console.log($('.select[data-id]').map(function() {
  return this.dataset.id;
}).get());

//vanilla
console.log([].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.select[data-id]'), function(el) {
  return el.dataset.id;
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="select" data-id="1">one</span>
<span class="select" data-id="2">two</span>
<span class="select" data-id="3">three</span>
<span class="select" data-id="4">one</span>
<span class="select" data-id="5">two</span>
<span class="select" data-id="6">three</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```js
$('[data-id]').each( function(e){
 var $el = $(this);
 if($el.hasClass('test')) {
  console.log($el.attr('data-id')) 
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="test" data-id="1"></li>
 <li data-id="2"></li>
 <li class="test" data-id="3"></li>
 <li data-id="4"></li>
 <li class="test" data-id="5"></li>
</ul>
```